# JASP and Statsmodels (Python) returning different results for multiple linear regression

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression, statsmodels

I'm running a multiple linear regression analysis in Python's statsmodels and in JASP. I'm using the same dataset and, as far as I can understand, I'm using the same model. I'm pretty sure I'm coding it right in Python (see below). I assume this might be related to some underlying difference between JASP and statsmodels, but not sure. Am I right?

Any comment highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Code I'm using in python:

```
model = smf.ols('outcome ~ predictor1 + C(predictor2) + predictor1*C(predictor2)', data = dataset).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

(obs. predictor1 is continuous; predictor2 is categorical)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the summary tables for both. I have no idea what JASP is doing. My guess would be that categorical variables are encoded differently by default. If that is the the case, then parameters will differ, but the predicted values and statistics like Rsquared should be the same.

Comment: I agree with the ideas from Josef. I think it would help if you show your JASP code too. Also, this problem is simple enough that you can construct an equivalent model and solve it more or less by hand using your tool of choice (Python, R, Excel, etc). Maybe simplify it even more by removing the categorical variables. Verify that you can get equivalent results for the simplest possible model and go from there.

Comment: @Josef and @RobertDodier Thanks! Indeed, when I remove the categorical specifier (C) (`outcome ~ predictor1 + predictor2 + predictor1*predictor2`) JASP and Python return identical results. And, yes, statistics like Rsqrd were the same. Can I consider the second model, without the categorical specifier (C), correct even though the variable is categorical? Wouldn't the first one be more correct? If so, why JASP don't take this into consideration?
Thanks again! I can still upload print screens with outputs and JASP "input options" window if you think will help.